# How to alter an uploaded image resolution using PHP before storing in mysql BLOB field

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have created a MySQL database 'tutorial_db' and in that database I have created a table with 3 columns:

[image: The image table in my tutorial_db]

I have written the following code using PHP and HTML to upload an image file and store it in the longblob 'image' column and display all the images from the database in the same page:

```
<?php
//connect to database
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'tutorial_db') or die('Could not connect to database: '.mysqli_connect_error());
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Upload Image</title>
</head>
<form action="image.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p><input type="file" name="image"></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="upload_image" value="Upload"></p>
</form>
<?php
error_reporting(0);
if(isset($_POST['upload_image'])) {
    //check if an image file is uploaded or not.
    if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) == FALSE) {
        //this block is executed if a non-image file or no file is uploaded
        echo 'Please upload an image!'; 
    } else {
        //this block is executed if an image is uploaded
        $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
        $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

        //query to insert images in the table
        if(!mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO image(image_name, image) VALUES('$image_name', '$image')")) {
            echo "Failed to upload image!";
        }
    }
    //query to display all the images stored in the image database
    $record = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM image");
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($record)) {
        echo '<img width = "20%" height = "200px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $rows['image'] ).'"/>';
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}

?>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

It is working perfectly fine for images with resolution lower than 1920x1080. But when I try uploading images of resolution, say for example: 3840x2160 it displays the uploading failed error. I am guessing it is due to the image resolution that the error is being displayed. Is there any way to reduce the resolution of such images before storing them in the MySQL database?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) (addslashes is utterly USELESS as a defense mechanism), and testing for tmp_name==false is NOT how you validate an upload. there's a `['error']` parameter in $_FILES for exactly that purpose. as well, note that XxY resolution is a useless indicator. a 10,000 x 10,000 all-white jpeg is ~300k. it's the size of the file that matters. not the number of pixels in it.

Comment: @MarcB The file with the resolution 3840x2160 that I was trying to upload was of 3MB. I guess longblob can handle sizes much greater than that. And thanks for the upload validation suggestion.